# How to export syntax highlighting rules from vim to vimrc format

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

When I analyze log files in `vim` I often create ad-hoc syntax highlighting rules for better orientation. For example

```
:syntax match myerror match /NullPointerException/
:highlight myerror ctermbg=red
```

So far so good. But sometimes I create quite complex rules during a long editing session and I want to save all created ad-hoc rules so I can reuse them. I can print them:

```
:syntax
myerror        xxx match /NullPointerException/
:highlight
myerror        xxx ctermbg=4
```

But this output contains not only ad-hoc rules and it cannot be simply copied to `.vimrc` or to a new syntax file because of different format. The `:makevimrc` does not save syntax highlighting rules at all.

Any idea how to export ad-hoc coloring rules?

Comment: To my knowledge Vim does not provide a mechanism for this. I'd copy them from my :-command history by typing `q:` (q, colon) in normal mode and searching for them.

Comment: @Heptite: Good hint! I realized that it is possible to edit the command history so I can do `q:` and then delete all non syntax commands `:g!/^sy/d` and copy all of them. And the to the same for `hi`. Thanks.

Comment: Since you were able to come up with a full solution, you can answer your own question with full instructions and then mark it as accepted.

Comment: I do not think it is a full solution. I would give +1 to answer like this but would not accept because I still hope there is more convenient way. If nobody comes with a better solution the I will perhaps write a function based on comments above, past it here and it could be an acceptable answer from my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no native Vim mechanism to do this.  I think it's assumed that if you are going to develop a syntax highlight rule set you will do it in a Vim script from the start.

I threw together a simple Vim script that will append all syntax and highlight commands from the :-command history into a named file:

```
function! GetSyntaxHistory()
    let l:lines=[]
    for l:i in range(1,histnr(':'))
        let l:line = histget(':', l:i)
        if l:line =~ '^\s*\(syn\|syntax\|hi\|highlight\)\s\+'
            let l:lines += [l:line]
        endif
    endfor
    return l:lines
endfunction

function! WriteSyntax(file)
    let l:lines = GetSyntaxHistory()
    call writefile(l:lines, a:file, 'a')
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -complete=file ExportSyn call WriteSyntax(<f-args>)
```